# Can we Sense our Prarabdha?

Tags: karma

Normal persons have no power to sense events before their birth and some are not even aware of their own conscience.

When a painful hardship befalls to a person how ( or by what means ) does one determine if it should be suffered anyway as carried forward Prarabdha from a previous birth (silently endured), or should it be immediately repulsed as a self-defending retaliatory action? There is a danger of increasing Prarabdha balance if a wrong choice is made.

The guiding voice of *maanassakhi* is active in conscientious persons so there is no problem. However for the vast majority.. with a guru or a specific stothra or mantra, it might be of some help.

Comment: Wait you should always try avoid suffering even tbough its prarabdha. Because all suffering is because of bad karma and prarabdha. How else can you suffer?? All pain is brough by bad karma and you have got to try to avoid it.